# Airflow AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'query'

Tags: airflow

I am writing an airflow dynamic dag python file . In the "end" task , i had passed an "on_success_callback" to clear the Xcom if data is older than 30 days . But it is throwing error as follows.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1617, in _run_finished_callback
    callback(context)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 72, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/db_load.py", line 443, in cleanup_xcom
    session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.execution_date <= ts_limit).delete()
AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'query'
```

```
code : 

@provide_session
def cleanup_xcom(session=None):
    ts_limit = datetime.now(timezone.utc) - timedelta(days=30)
    session.query(XCom).filter(XCom.execution_date <= ts_limit).delete()
    logging.info(f"deleted all XCOMs older than {ts_limit}")


 end = PythonOperator(
            task_id="end",
            python_callable=audit_end,
            on_success_callback=cleanup_xcom,
            provide_context=True,
            trigger_rule='all_done',
            op_kwargs={'job_name': pd_name, 'job_type': 'airflow'},
            dag=dag
        )
```

I tried to delete the Xcom values older than 30 days . But the airflow task is throwing error